# SIP Error 481 Call/Transcation Does Not Exist when transferring

Tags: sip, wireshark, telephony, sip-server

Our phones are done through SIP and we were noticing this error appearing on our server.

After running tests, we have determined that it only appears on inbound calls from external numbers, when we attempt to transfer that call to an internal extension. Outbound calls transferred do not produce the error.

What is strange is that, even after showing this error, the call **continues fine**. Everyone can still talk, the new extension picks up the call fine. So with the actual telecommunication, there is no probem. However we do need to find out what is causing this error because it is causing havoc with our SIP call recorder.

Here is the wireshark trace we are getting on an independent call. At time 29 is when the internal transfer is made.

[image: Wireshark screenshot with numbers blacked]

I understand that this error is caused by a UAS receiving a SIP packet for  call of which it is not aware. However thati s about where my knowledge ends. In the first instance of the error, I am curious as to whether the source being the external gateway IP means that is a problem at the other end? This can't be the case as it happens on calls from anyone.

Thanks in advance!

**Packet headers**

[545](http://oi61.tinypic.com/2i0b57o.jpg) [1248](http://oi62.tinypic.com/so5pav.jpg) [3945](http://oi61.tinypic.com/28u2o11.jpg) [3950](http://i61.tinypic.com/2eob95x.png)

Comment: It is difficult to say what's going on. There's an INVITE from A (91.146.112.10) to B (192.168.0.250) (not sure what kind of animal are each of them). This INVITE gets (apparently) accepted. Then there's other INVITE from B to A. This is a RE-INVITE (as wireshark labels it as *in-dialog*). This is (apparently) rejected with 481... if you could show the SIP headers in packets 545,1248, 3945 and 3950... perhaps we can understand more. Also what kind of architecture (is your *server* a B2BUA Application or a SIP Proxy)

Comment: Hi jsantander; packet headers requested added to the question. I am afraid I don't know what architecture I am on; could probably find out if required.

Comment: Also IPs: 192.168.0.250 is the phone system, 91.146.112.10 is the external SIP (not sure exactly what). I don't know what 194.247.239.222 is. Not sure but is the fact that the first invite and the second invite have different IPs after them?

Comment: I'm sorry. I cannot see anything wrong. to summarize: External sends INVITE to a user in 194.246.239.222. Without a Route header, this is routed by Request-URI, so *194.246.239.222 must be related somehow to the Phone system (192.168.0.250)*. This session is established with the 200 OK and correct Call-ID and local and remote tags are exchanged. The Phone-System sends a RE-INVITE (with the same Call-ID and matching local and remote tags) the RE-INVITE is sent to the Contact header received in the original INVITE (through Request-URI)... It is the External SIP the one signaling the error.

Comment: Okay; define "External SIP". Could this be a problem with the SIP gateway (the SIP provider's problem?).

Comment: I only said that 91.146.112.10 is the one complaining about an apparently correct RE-INVITE.